# "Wait" for a clock cycle in VHDL process

Tags: vhdl

Let's say that there is a RAM component entity as below

```
entity RAM is
   port(
      -- other port such as clk, reset, ...
      en: in std_logic;
      addr: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      dataR: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end RAM;
```

RAM specification is that when `en = '1'`, the value stored at `addr` is available on `dataR` one clock cycle afterwards.

For now, my process in which I use the RAM component looks like this:

```
process(state)
begin
  case(state) is
    -- ...
    when ReadMemory =>
       addr <= "00000000";
       en <= '1';
       next_mem <= dataR;

    -- ...
  end case;
end process;
```

This design does not work because because `dataR` is read on the same clock cycle as when `addr` and `en` are set.

How can I "wait" a single clck cycle in order to read the correct value from the memory ?

Comment: *"RAM specification is that when en = '1', the value stored at addr is available on dataR one clock cycle afterwards."* What clock? The RAM interface has no clock!

Comment: And also, there isn't any clock **at all** in the code you show ! You'll have to show more code, all the RAM code actually to get some usefull help. A RAM code is usually not that big. consider providing an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The sensitivity list of `process(state)` is not complete... This question makes no sense, there is no clock in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a finite state machine, so you can use a "waiting" state

```
process(state)
begin
    case(state) is
    -- ...
        when ReadMemory =>
            addr <= "00000000";
            en <= '1';

            next_state <= WaitMemory;
        when WaitMemory =>
            next_mem <= dataR;
            next_state <= another_state;
    -- ...
    end case;
end process;
```

Be careful, with certain kind of finite state machine you could have to wait 2 clocks. To be more specififc, with this kind of FSM :

```
process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        state <= next_state;
    end if;
end process;

process(state)
begin
    case(state) is
    -- ...
       -- YOUR FSM with next_state attribution
    -- ...
    end case;
end process;
```

You have to wait 1 clock.
But with this one :

```
process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        case(state) is
        -- ...
           -- YOUR FSM with state attribution
        -- ...
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

You will have to wait 2 clocks